# Bootstrap button toggle class issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a rather frustrating issues i'm not understanding with jQuery and Bootstrap/CSS. As you can see from this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLxhj4ht/2/) . When clicking the blue category button it doesn't apply the new new CSS class but the other button displays it fine, any ideas why this is occurring?

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_IncCat">Category</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn_IncCat2">Category</button>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-color: #357ebd;
}
.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #4cae4c;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_IncCat').click(function () {
        //  $('#btn_IncCat').css({ 'background-color': '#5cb85c','border-color': '#4cae4c' })
        $('#btn_IncCat').toggleClass('btn btn-success')
    })
})
```

Comment: On click of the button you remove the `btn-primary` class which provides the button with its styling. What behaviour are you expecting to have?

Comment: you're trying to do like, when click on button, it will show green and next time when you click on that it turns to blue? right

Comment: I just want to swap the btn-primary with btn-success

Comment: Yeah amtest, just  want to swap classes on button clicks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use $('#btn_IncCat').toggleClass('btn success') is similar to

```
if($('#btn_IncCat').hasClass('btn btn-success')) {
    $('#btn_IncCat').removeClass('btn btn-success')
} else {
    $('#btn_IncCat').addClass('btn btn-success')
}
```

the first problem was that you dont need to remove the btn class, bootstrap uses this class to set the padding, border, border radius, margin and other properties you only wanted to change the color, wich is specified in the class btn-primary so instead of

```
$('#btn_IncCat').toggleClass('btn btn-success');
```

do

```
if ($('#btn_IncCat').hasClass('btn-success')) {
    $('#btn_IncCat').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-primary');
} else {
    $('#btn_IncCat').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');
}
```

or even better

```
$('#btn_IncCat').toggleClass('btn-primary btn-success')
```

here the example http://jsfiddle.net/wLxhj4ht/5/

Comment: thanks that did it. Was i using toggleclass in the wrong context?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, this is really simple.

When you do

```
   $('#btn_IncCat').toggleClass('btn btn-success')
```

You're switching each class given as the argument.
You gave `btn` and `btn-success`, so when you click the button, it switches them off.

But you want to keep `btn` class right? So you should not toggle it. You want to switch `btn-primary` and `btn-success` alternately. So you change your code to:

```
   $('#btn_IncCat').toggleClass('btn-primary btn-success')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wLxhj4ht/4/

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
id="btn_IncCat">Category</button>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#btn_IncCat').click(function () {
      if($(this).hasClass('btn-primary')){
        $(this).removeClass('btn-primary');
        $(this).addClass('btn-success');
      }else{
        $(this).removeClass('btn-success');
        $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
      }
  });
});
```